# Isotope: display active selected value on button label

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I use a Isotope Filter to filter  based on the active selected option.

Once the option is selected, the corresponding  is filtered. When "Option A" is selected, only "A div" are shown and that's correct.

Example here:

https://www.freemotion.it/test.php

I would like to have the label of the selecting button showing the current active label option name.

When "A option" is selected the label of the button still shows "ALL options" while it should shows the current selected option label like "A option" or "B option".

["ALL options" is the default view]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otb0m.png)

[Once "A options" is selected the label of the button still shows the default "ALL option"]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd0SK.png)

Please note this is only in "max width" 767px screen. Above, the layout is different and there are no issues.